# why the h1 tag for the clock is not completely centered vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a pomodoro clock that the h1 tag displaying the clock timer is not centered vertically (center of page). how could I center the text vertically without losing horizontal alignment? Also if someone can suggest how could I bring the - (minus) and + (plus) signs inside the controls closer to the middle without moving the text.

```css
body {
  background-color: #545454;
}

.title {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.clockContainer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.timer {
  margin: 0 50px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  font-size: 44px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.controlContainer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.control {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.time {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.minus {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.plus {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- header title -->
  <div class="title primary-text">
    <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- clock container -->
  <div class="clockContainer">
    <h2>Session</h2>
    <!-- timer / clock -->
    <div class="timer">
      <h1 class="display">23:59</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- this section for controlling clock -->
    <div class="controlContainer">
      <div class="control">
        <div class="button title">Start</div>
        <div class="button hide title">Stop</div>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <h3 class="time">30</h3>
        <h3 class="title work">Work</h3>
        <h3 class="minWork ticker minus">-</h3>
        <h3 class="plusWork ticker plus">+</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <h3 class="time">10</h3>
        <h3 class="title break">Break</h3>
        <h3 class="minBrake ticker minus">-</h3>
        <h3 class="plusBrake ticker plus">+</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear but try applying this to the element:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This will align the h1 the way you want I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `height` for `.timer` to center `h1`. Due to fixed `height`, `h1` is not centered because it is bigger than `200px`. If you want to decrease `height` of `.timer` just decrease `h1`'s `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

To move `+` and `-` closer to middle decrease `margin-top` values for `.ticker` (e.g. from `0` to `-5px`). Demo:

```css
body {
  background-color: #545454;
}

.title {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.clockContainer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.timer {
  margin: 0 50px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  font-size: 44px;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.controlContainer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.control {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.time {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.minus {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.plus {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- header title -->
  <div class="title primary-text">
    <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- clock container -->
  <div class="clockContainer">
    <h2>Session</h2>
    <!-- timer / clock -->
    <div class="timer">
      <h1 class="display">23:59</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- this section for controlling clock -->
    <div class="controlContainer">
      <div class="control">
        <div class="button title">Start</div>
        <div class="button hide title">Stop</div>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <h3 class="time">30</h3>
        <h3 class="title work">Work</h3>
        <h3 class="minWork ticker minus">-</h3>
        <h3 class="plusWork ticker plus">+</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <h3 class="time">10</h3>
        <h3 class="title break">Break</h3>
        <h3 class="minBrake ticker minus">-</h3>
        <h3 class="plusBrake ticker plus">+</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```